# Typescript wont find .d.ts files

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, graphql, apollo

Currently working on a project of mine and wanted to use a library called [merge-graphql-schemas](https://github.com/okgrow/merge-graphql-schemas). As the module does not have its own typings i created a file located in src/types/merge-graphql-schemas.d.ts

Within merge-graphql-schemas.d.ts i wrote:

```
declare module "merge-graphql-schemas";
```

My TSlint removes the errors in the file importing:

```
import { mergeTypes, mergeResolvers } from "merge-graphql-schemas";
```

But when i compile i still get:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'merge-graphql-schemas'
Try `npm install @types/merge-graphql-schemas` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'merge-graphql-schemas';`
```

I've also tried solutions like:

```
declare module "*";
```

**Thanks in advance**

**EDIT:**
Using this resolved my problem

```
// tslint:disable-next-line
const variableName = require('merge-graphql-schemas')
```

If anyone can explain why or come up with a different solution i'd be happy to hear it

Comment: tried importing via - `/// <reference path="merge-graphql-schemas.d.ts"/>`?

Comment: You mean like `/// <reference path="path/to/my/typing/type.d.ts"/>

import { mergeTypes, mergeResolvers } from "merge-graphql-schemas"; `@IshankDubey

Comment: Try `require` instead of `import`.

Comment: `const mgs = require('merge-graphql-schemas')`  ? @eduPeeth

Comment: `var merge-graphql-schemas  = require('merge-graphql-schemas');` and if it works you shall be able to use `merge-graphql-schemas` as reference.

Comment: It works, i am however interested in knowing why! @eduPeeth

Comment: @Seltiix, Glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer if it was any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `const merge-graphql-schemas = require('merge-graphql-schemas');`

There are some features that are not fully compatible with ES6 when it comes to Node.js. Like, if you try to use filesystem `fs` using the import style above, it won't work, even though that is what will be suggested to you by TS Lint.